# Difficulty installing TensorFlow and running MNIST example

Tags: r, tensorflow

I've come across a problem installing TensorFlow. Here is the code I ran to install:

```
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow(version = "1.5.0")
```

I was unable to install TensorFlow through RStudio any other way without receiving some sort of error.

The example I'm trying to run can be found [here](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tensorflow/articles/tutorial_mnist_beginners.html).

When running the first three lines of code:

```
datasets <- tf$contrib$learn$datasets
mnist <- datasets$mnist$read_data_sets("MNIST-data", one_hot = TRUE)

x <- tf$placeholder(tf$float32, shape(NULL, 784L))
```

Everything is fine, but when I run:

```
W <- tf$Variable(tf$zeros(shape(784L, 10L)))
```

I get the error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  UnboundLocalError: local variable 'self' referenced before assignment
```

I also get this error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
  SystemError: <built-in function AppendFloat32ArrayToTensorProto> returned NULL without setting an error
```

There is a detailed traceback I can give if necessary, but was wondering if there's any fix or if I did something wrong in the installation process?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed around and here are the steps that I took to install TensorFlow and have it running fine.

First, I uninstalled the TensorFlow package (and Keras package). This can be done either through the console by typing:

```
remove.packages("tensorflow")
remove.packages("keras")
```

A different way can be going to the packages in RStudio and clicking the x with a circle on the right side of the package.

Next, if Anaconda3 is installed, uninstall it. I didn't test if I could try and only delete the r-tensorflow folder in Anaconda3.

Afterwards, in the console, type:

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
library(keras)
install_keras()
```

Here, I ran into some errors. Go to the terminal and type:

```
sudo /usr/bin/easy_install pip
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

The second line might cause a problem, which can be solved by typing:

```
sudo easy_install nose
sudo easy_install tornado
```

Go back to RStudio and in the console, type:

```
install_keras()
```

That should fix the issue and TensorFlow should be good to use as Keras needs TensorFlow.

I think the issue stems from the new version of TensorFlow, version 1.9.